# Unresolved import, urllib2 error in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7

I just installed PyDev in Eclipse and the following line fails on me:

```
import urllib2
```

So, to verify, i opened python in interpreter mode(outside of Eclipse) and tried to import urllib2, it seems to work.

I tried `import sys` in Eclipse and that seems to be work fine.

I think urllib2 comes packaged with standard Python installation. Is there an explicit path i need to set in my Eclipse?

Comment: @Chander.. If your problem is solved, then you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add path till `python.exe` in Eclipse in below path: -

**Windows** -> **Preferences** -> **PyDev** -> **Interpreter Python** -> New

Then add the list of folders from Python home directory to your `PYTHON PATH`